# pstopdf mac terminal width and height options

Tags: macos, terminal.app

Are there any options which set width and height of outcome document of pstopdf command in terminal? I've used a2ps command to convert my Java code files into .ps file, now I want to convert .ps file to pdf using terminal, but it keeps cutting the right edge of the document, because it has some default size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [this blog entry](http://oapeon.blogspot.de/2007/09/setting-output-page-size-with-ps2pdf.html), use `identify` from ImageMagick:

> ```
> $ identify test.ps
>
> test.ps PS 609x1528 609x1528+0+0 PseudoClass 256c 909kb 0.020u 0:01
> ```
>
> Execute ps2pdf with the -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS and -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS arguments
>
> ```
> $ ps2pdf -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=679 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=1598 test.ps
> test.pdf
> ```

Comment: These commands are not in the default mac terminal, how can I get them?
EDIT: Oh I see, I have to download ImageMagick package. I was more thinking of a solution for default pstopdf command, but your answer is pretty cool as well.

Comment: Plagiarized: http://oapeon.blogspot.de/2007/09/setting-output-page-size-with-ps2pdf.html — I'm editing this to be quoted properly and keeping the useful information but this is an exception.

Comment: This answer uses `ps2pdf`, which is part of GhostScript, not `pstodf`, which is the MacOS built-in command. The latter does not have a `-d` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than forcing a page size on the input to `pstopdf`, you need to define the page size of the output from `a2ps`.

You need to use the `--setpagedevice` option, e.g. for A4:

```
--setpagedevice=PageSize:"[595 842]"
```

You can set a specific value as the default by adding the line:

`Options: --setpagedevice=PageSize:"[595 842]"` to the `a2ps-site.cfg` file.